# Prove Summation to Some Number $n$

Tags: summation, arithmetic

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Can someone help me prove this by induction:

$$\sum _{i=0}^{n}{i} =\frac { n\left( n+1 \right)  }{ 2 } .$$

Comment: I assume $x$ is natural number, what did you tried?

Comment: Assuming $x$ is a natural number, then $\sum_{i=0}^x{a}=xa$ because the term $a$ doesn't depend on $x$ at all (as you've written it).  Did you instead mean to write $\sum_{i=0}^x{x}$?  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @OfirSchnabel This is what I understood so far: Due to the fact that it is true for x=1, then it is true for x=2 
Due to the fact that it is true for x=2, then it is true for x=3
etc.
This shows that the statement should be true for every x.

Comment: Sorry guys its supposed to be an i instead of a.

Comment: I edit your question.

Comment: $i=0$ is unnecessary.

Comment: What is your induction assumption? please with details.

Comment: induction rules:  prove base case (n=1).  Then assume $n=k$  Using your assumption identity, show that $n=k+1$ also holds.

Comment: For even more fun, try it without induction  
$1+n=n+1$, $2+(n-1)=n+1$, ..., $k+(n-(k+1))=n+1$

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate..., many times over!

Comment: Thanks for finding one of the duplicates, @Arkamis!

Answer (score 0):

when $n=0$ then the formula is true.

suppose that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i=\frac{1}{2}(n(n-1))$.

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} i=n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i=n+\frac{1}{2}(n(n-1))=\frac{1}{2}(n(n+1))$

Answer (score 0):

***HINT:*** Induction works like this: you start by the lower most value and put it in the equation to verify it. Next, you assume the equation to be true for some value $k$. Then try to prove that it works for $k+1$ as well.

Using $\sum_{i=1}^{k}i=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, can you prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$ as well?

Comment: I didn't start from 0 because it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$  Then

$$1=\sum_{i=1}^1{i}=\frac{1(1+1)}{2}=1$$

Now assume $n=k$.  Thus

$$\sum_{i=1}^k{i}=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=1$$

If now $n=k+1$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{i}=\left[\sum_{i=1}^k{i}\right]+(k+1)=$$

What does the bracketed term equal?  Use algebra to solve.

Answer (score 0):

$n=1$ is clear.

Assume $$\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{(n-1)n}{2}.$$
Then $$\sum _{i=1}^{n}i=\left(\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}i\right)+n=\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+n=
\frac{(n-1)n+2n}{2}=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}.$$

Comment: @amWHY Is this the proof?

Comment: Is this the complete proof?